# How to include Jar file in AWS Lambda Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, jdbc, aws-lambda

I have a very simple issue. I am not able to consume a jar file in my AWS Lambda Function (Python). I need it to connect to a virtual data source using JDBC.
I did try including it in layers (zipped and unzipped both) but it didn't work.

The last resort is of-course creating the full deployment package but I want to avoid that !

Can anyone please help ?

Below is my lambda code :

````
import jaydebeapi as jd
import os 

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    uid='dummy_user'
    pwd='dummy_pswd'
    driver_class = 'com.biovia.jdbc.openaccess.OpenAccessDriver'
    driver_file='/disco-jdbc.jar'
    connection_string='jdbc:dataaccess://usbdbanapp9001.corp.inbaxalta.com:11706;ServerDataSource=disco'

    con = jd.connect(driver_class, connection_string, [uid, pwd], driver_file)

    print('successfully connected !!')

    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    } ```
````

Comment: How did you specify the path when using layers?

Comment: I just zipped the external packages and created the layers using them. they are working fine. I thought I can do the same with JAR file, but it didn't work.  Any suggestions ?

Comment: How complicated is your code besides the database?  This seems like an unholy combination and, knowing both Python and Java, I'd think it would be easier to write the Lambda in Java.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this? I'm facing the same problem.